# Cassandra HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: cassandra

I came in today only to find that all 3 of our cassandra nodes in one of our labs was down. I keep seeing this `INFO` message in the logs. Does this mean that cassandra is running out of memory?

```
   INFO  [main] 2020-10-12 15:11:56,014 CassandraDaemon.java:493 - JVM Arguments: [-Xloggc:/opt/cassandra/logs/gc.log, -ea, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:-UseBiasedLocking, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled, -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10, -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M, -Xms899M, -Xmx899M, -Xmn200M, -XX:+UseCondCardMark, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/opt/cassandra/conf/hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:/opt/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=7199, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7199, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password, -Djava.library.path=/opt/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/opt/cassandra/logs, -Dcassandra.storagedir=/opt/cassandra/data, -Dcassandra-pidfile=/var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid]
```

They're running in Amazon EC2. Would the next logical course of action be to increase the node size?

Comment: That looks more like it is starting, due to some auto-restart on the daemon - can you check for WARN / ERROR entries

Comment: OK thanks, I will.